# View Product Quantity based on Base UoM and Purchase UoM in OpenERP 7

Tags: openerp-7

I am using different units of measure for the same products.  Say 1 mL as a base unit of measure, 1 Litre can as purchase unit of measure.

Is it possible in OpenERP7 to view the product quantity based on both UoMs?

For example, if I buy 5 quantities of a 1-Litre can, it should display as:

**Qty 5** (based on Purchase UoM) and **Qty 5000** (based on Base UoM).

Is it possible?